# Default HttpTriggerAttribute in .NET Core (v2) Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have to make an Azure Function App in .NET Core with a large number of functions.

All of the methods will have the same the same signature:

```
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Is there a way to simplify this a little? For example:

```
Run([DefaultHttpTrigger]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Or even better:

```
Run(DefaultHttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

I tried to make a new `DefaultHttpTriggerAttribute` inheriting from `HttpTriggerAttribute`, but the later is a sealed class so I could not inherit it.

Comment: what is your goal? cleaner code or something? you will still have to shove the `POST` and `AuthorizationLevel` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/HttpTriggerAttribute.cs) the default AuthorizationLevel is `Function`. So if you need anything different than that, you need to specify it in the attribute. For the methods, if you don't specify (= restrict) them, all HTTP methods are accepted.

Since, as you already said, the class is sealed, you cannot inherit etc. from it. So I don't see a way around specifying it for every Function you want to expose.

Comment: I know. That's why I wrote it that way?! If they need something different than Function, they do need to specify it.